# Rails 5.2 show methods don't need to exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Has anyone else noticed that in rails 5.2 (not sure if this happens in other versions), you can scaffold out a controller and then delete the show method, provided the view for show action still exists rails will render the show action with the relevant data.

This seems very very wrong to me. Has anyone else noticed this? If this is intended behavior I think a console warning or something should be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of rail's "convention over configuration" philosophy. As stated in the [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action):

> You've heard that Rails promotes "convention over configuration". Default rendering is an excellent example of this. By default, controllers in Rails automatically render views with names that correspond to valid routes.

While it may seem very wrong to you, it is the explicitly intended behavior.